# c# dllimport of MsiGetShortcutTarget(msi.dll) failed with error 1603 under Windows 7

Tags: c#, windows-installer, dllimport

I want to resolve an advertised MSI shortcut in c# as described here:
[How to parse "special" .lnk files, aka. MSI shortcuts aka. Windows Installer advertised shortcuts using C#](http://www.geektieguy.com/2007/11/19/how-to-parse-special-lnk-files-aka-msi-shortcuts-aka-windows-installer-advertised-shortcuts-using-c/)

```
[DllImport("msi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
private static extern UInt32 MsiGetShortcutTarget(
    string szShortcutTarget,
    [Out] StringBuilder szProductCode,
    [Out] StringBuilder szFeatureId,
    [Out] StringBuilder szComponentCode);

public static string ParseShortcut(string file)
{
    StringBuilder product = new StringBuilder(MaxGuidLength + 1);
    StringBuilder feature = new StringBuilder(MaxFeatureLength + 1);
    StringBuilder component = new StringBuilder(MaxGuidLength + 1);

    UInt32 res = MsiGetShortcutTarget(file, product, feature, component);
    ...
}
```

I use VS 2010 and tried with different settings for "Platform target" and/or "Target framework". MsiGetShortcutTarget always returns 1603 (A fatal error occurred during installation) under Windows 7.

I tried to do the same with c++ and I can resolve the Shortcut and everything is fine. I also tested with a msi.dll, that I copied from a Windows XP and this dll can resolve the Shortcut with the C# code. I have no idea why the c# code won't work with the msi.dll under Windows 7.

I testet MsiGetComponentPath with a known product GUID and component GUID to resolve the target path in c# with the dll, that returns 1603 for MsiGetShortcutTarget and it works perfectly. So only MsiGetComponentPath fails under Windows 7 and I don't know why it went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems related to the way COM is initialized.

If I add `[STAThread]` to my `Main` method, it works fine (well, if you actually use `StringBuilder` instead of `char[]` for your arguments :-), but I get a return value of 1603 when using MTA.

Comment: char[] was just an other test, should be StringBuilder thats right.

Answer (score 0):

I highly suggest taking a look at WiX's Deployment Tools Foundation.  It  has a really nice interop library developed by a MSFT employee that makes calling MSI easy.

For example, the Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller namespace has an Installer class that exposes a static method ShortcutTarget GetShortcutTarget( string shortcut ).   The ShortcutTarget class then has get accessors for ComponentCode, Feature and ProductCode.

Additionalyl this is an open source project so if you really, really want to know how the P/Invoke stuff works you can look at the code.